# How to get today's date using SQLAlchemy ORM datatype?

Tags: python, types, sqlalchemy, orm

How can I get today's date with ORM SQLAlchemy? How do datatypes work when mixing SQLAlchemy and Python types?

Note, I am trying to use the ORM methodology exclusively.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Float, String, Integer, DateTime, select
from sqlalchemy import Table, Date, MetaData, text, cast, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped, query

#Import CSV specific
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt     #So as not to conflict with SQLAlchemy datatypes
from datetime import date as DT

#Constants
today = dt.today()
database_name = 'lite.db'
table_name = 'General'
cols = ["STATED_KEY", "REPORT_DATE", "TRADE_ID", "Description"]
Dates = ["REPORT_DATE"]

def db_from_csv(database_name, table_name):     #Loads CSV file via Pandas
    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=cols, parse_dates=Dates)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    with conn:
        df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Please feel free to criticize the code bellow. I am trying to write current (not deprecated), "best practices", "properly writen" code.

```py
class Base(DeclarativeBase): #MetaData object where Table objects are collected
    pass

class General(Base):
    __tablename__   = "General"

    STATED_KEY: Mapped[int]                 = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key =True)
    Report_DATE: Mapped[DateTime]           = mapped_column(DateTime)
    Transaction_ID: Mapped[int]             = mapped_column(Integer)
    Description: Mapped[str]                = mapped_column(String)

#Initiate database connection
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///lite.db', echo=False)#, echo=True, future=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)    #Create the tables
db_from_csv(database_name, table_name)  #Populate the db with the CSV
```

I've tried various ways to quantify today (get todays date as mm/dd/YYYY) so I get a boolean answer when comparing: date1 < date2. This should be true or false.

Things I've tried that don't work I have commented out.

```py
#today = session.execute((func.current_date))
#today = session.query(General.Transaction).filter(func.DATE(General.Transaction.datetime) == DT.today())
#today = DateTime(today)
#today = dt.today()
#today = DateTime(today)

today = func.current_date()
some_date = session.query(General.Report_DATE).first()
print(type(today), type(some_date))
print(today > some_date)
```

Result of print statements.

```py
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.functions.current_date'> <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>
CURRENT_DATE > :current_date_1 #   <---- I'm expecting a boolean result. What is this?
```

The question is not only "I want the answer" but, a little explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the result of all the todays?

Comment: Yes, one moment.

Comment: can you clarify what exactly is the question? title says "get today's date", towards the end of the question you say "I'm expecting a boolean result.", how can today's date be a boolean?

Comment: yes! @python_user I mean get today's date in order to get a boolean. That way I can compare it to another date.

 Precisely, is it before: "date1 < date2" The answer should be boolean. 

I'll change the title to be more precise.

Comment: you mention "get todays date as mm/dd/YYYY" but you are using a `DateTime` and not `Date` type, so which is it? or do you mean you want to only use the date component from the DateTime?

Comment: if you want to compare only the date component of `General.Report_DATE` with current date you can do `session.query(func.current_date() > cast(General.Report_DATE, Date)).first()`, import `cast` and `Date` from `sqlalchemy`

Comment: @python_user Actually! In this case I only need the date. BUT. When I was making the class, when I set the column as DATE, I had all sorts of problems when loading a CSV values and had to set it to DATETIME. I tried cast and func but couldn't make it work. It seems it is working. Thank you! I will try and format this best so it can help the next person. Just a moment.

Comment: if you feel my suggestion worked, you can self answer the question

Comment: Yes, I'll format it in the clearest way I can.